# How can I specify the account from which I want to send an email using VBA

Tags: vba, email, excel

I have a macro that send email automatically using VBA. On my Outllok, I have 3 different account/emails setup from which I can send emails.

Here is my macro

```
Set olapp = New Outlook.Application
Set msg = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    msg.To = Sheets("CONFIRM").Range("G2")
    msg.Subject = Subj
    msg.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    msg.HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:calibri;font-size:15'>" & Body & "</p>"
    msg.Attachments.Add (DestinationFile1)
    msg.Send
```

How can I specify which account to use to send the emails.... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

make 3 macros, one for each account, and call which one you want based on criteria. Or include a selection statement base on criteria for G1 G2 or G3 I presume

Comment: But I don't know how to specify an account in the macro? i don't how to say to VBA, when u send this email use this sender adress aaa@bbb.com

Comment: Here's a [reference](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/send-using-default-or-specific-account/) for that situation.

Comment: Thank you this works  using this method `.SentOnBehalfOfName = "alias@domain.com"`